# Joins on multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, join

Given this schema, is it possible to produce an output wherein it shows all the User's assigned modules with its matching enrollment id if any, and NULL if none?

```
Users
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | group_id |
+----+------+----------+
| 1  | Carl | 1        |
+----+------+----------+
| 2  | Joe  | 1        |
+----+------+----------+
| 3  | Dan  | 2        |
+----+------+----------+

Modules
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Alpha   |
+----+---------+
| 2  | Bravo   |
+----+---------+
| 3  | Charlie |
+----+---------+
| 4  | Delta   |
+----+---------+
| 5  | Echo    |
+----+---------+

Approved_Courses
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
| id | group_id | module | order_number |
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
| 1  | 1        | 1      | 1            |
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
| 2  | 1        | 2      | 2            |
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
| 3  | 1        | 3      | 3            |
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
| 4  | 2        | 1      | 1            |
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
| 5  | 2        | 3      | 2            |
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
| 6  | 2        | 2      | 3            |
+----+----------+--------+--------------+

Classes
+----+--------+
| id | module |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 1      |
+----+--------+
| 2  | 2      |
+----+--------+

Enrollments
+--------+----------+----------+
| id     | staff_id | class_id |
+--------+----------+----------+
| ENR-1  | 1        | 1        |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

My desired output would be below. I can't seem to do it without unnecessary duplicates and/or wrong information on enrollment.id

```
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| users.id | user.group_id | modules.id | module.order_number | enrollment |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 1        | 1             | 1          | 1                   | ENR-1      |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 1        | 1             | 2          | 2                   | NULL       |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 1        | 1             | 3          | 3                   | NULL       |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 2        | 1             | 1          | 1                   | NULL       |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 2        | 1             | 2          | 2                   | NULL       |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 2        | 1             | 3          | 3                   | NULL       |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 3        | 2             | 1          | 1                   | NULL       |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 3        | 2             | 2          | 3                   | NULL       |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 3        | 2             | 3          | 2                   | NULL       |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
```

I would appreciate any help.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3cc9d5/1

Comment: Fiddle structure/data do not match published in a question. At least in Enrollments.ID. Synchronize please.

Comment: Updated record values on Approved_Courses.id, and synced values on the fiddle provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.id,users.group_id,Approved_Courses.module 
      ,Approved_Courses.order_number , Enrollments.id
FROM 
Users full outer join 
approved_courses
  on users.group_id=approved_courses.group_id
left outer  join Classes 
  on Classes.id=Approved_Courses.group_id and Approved_Courses.module=Classes.module 
left outer join Enrollments
  on Classes.id=Enrollments.class_id 
 and Users.id=Enrollments.staff_id

order by users.id,users.group_id
        ,Approved_Courses.module ,Approved_Courses.order_number
```

[image]